# Lead acid battery for embedded system

Tags: batteries, embedded, charge, lead-acid

I am developing an embedded system that contains a 12 V lead-acid battery. The system is developed for 12 V vehicle applications, also using a 12 V lead-acid battery.
I am not so sure how to connect both batteries.
The capacity of the vehicle's battery is much more than the embedded system, so, we desire that the vehicle's battery could charge the embedded battery. In addition, when the vehicle's battery is turned off, the embedded battery could not supply all vehicle systems.

The illustration below is a secure connection for the system?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The vehicle's battery can not charge the embedded battery, particularly with a diode in series. The voltage will not be high enough.

If the alternator is working properly it might be able to charge the embedded battery, but only very slowly.

You could look for an ideal diode circuit between the vehicle's alternator and the embedded battery, but then you run the risk of dangerously overcharging the embedded battery.

I think you need to start with a dc-dc converter that boost the vehicles voltage up to 15V or so, then add a charging circuit to that.

Comment: Elliot, thanks for your comment. We desire a very low-cost product but after these comments, I do not doubt using a dc-dc converter.

Comment: @LucasDias If you need a low cost product why can't you simply use the vehicle battery instead of including a 2nd one? It doesn't make sense to be cheap about including a switch regulator while at the same time delivering an elephant-sized battery with each system. The shipping costs for the battery alone would fund countless switch regulators...

Answer (score 0):

Batteries have a limited lifespan and you need to think about your customer market specifications and requirements not only for initial use but fault detection and correction by replacement.

**Do you want it to be monitored on Canbus via the OBD diagnostics?**

**How will you charge it?** only when Vbus > 13.2V or ??

**How will you protect it** and the main battery bus ? Aux panel fuse? self fuse? PTC fuse? reverse blocking? active FET switch with UVP and OVP?

These are all designer choices that we cannot make for you, but you ought to understand the mechanisms and consequences of battery failure and include something in your design spec to determine how to complete the design.  Volume, cost, reliability and target markets all are variables in automotive after-market design.

Coincidentally, my GL350 has been reporting on the main display "Auxillary Battery Failure" after startup for a couple of months now. This means my aux battery has failed before my main battery and it may need replacement after diagnosis with the OBD tool or directly.

Often Aux batteries are SLA types which demand a thermally-compensated charge voltage slightly lower e.g. 13.8V, unlike flooded lead-acid cell batteries which nominally accept 14.2V when the engine is running.

Diodes vary their voltage drop with current and might not be precise enough to regulate that voltage for 100% SoC .  **What performance specs do you require?**

**Consider making a design spec to include the main topics;**
Performance , Environmental specs, Serviceability, Protection, Reliability,

Then compare your designs with industry leaders.

[image]

Comment: Tony, Thanks for your comments. I am evaluating with the customer all requirements but your points help me a lot.